# Screen freezing when using Firefox 5 in OS X

Tags: macos, freeze, firefox

I constantly need to move the windows of Firefox to get the page to visually refresh (like to unpin the window from the top).

The problem:  I'm on a page, I want to go anywhere else, or I click on a link.
**The screen stays on the same page until I move the browser window**.

The browser is **not freezing** because the page is already loaded, it's only a display problem.

It happens like 15 times a day. The only thing in common with the iMac and Macbook Pro (on which the problem happens): They both have Firebug installed. I tested the FF5 beta before upgrading to 5 stable (and up to date) on the two Macs too.

PS: My colleague has the exact same problem. (It's been happening since 2 months approx.)

Answer (score 0):

- Try disabling or uninstalling Firebug (perhaps just move its folder temporarily)
- Try running Firefox in Safe mode
- Try with a new Firefox profile
- Try in a new user account
- Try re-installing Firefox

Comment: When reinstalling Firefox, also delete `~/Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist`.